# Not sure what the value in a log message in auth log means?

Tags: ssh, logs

I have the following log line item in my auth.log file.

```
[TimeStamp] [server] sshd[####]: Received disconnect from [IP Address]: 11: disconnected by user
```

Obviously this is a disconnect log from an ssh session.  I know what it all means except for the  11.  What does this value indicate? Also is the form of this log message documented somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the reason code for the disconnection. From [the source](http://www.openssh.com/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/usr.bin/ssh/ssh2.h?rev=1.14;content-type=text%2Fx-cvsweb-markup;sortby=date):

```
/* disconnect reason code */

#define SSH2_DISCONNECT_HOST_NOT_ALLOWED_TO_CONNECT     1
#define SSH2_DISCONNECT_PROTOCOL_ERROR                  2
#define SSH2_DISCONNECT_KEY_EXCHANGE_FAILED             3
#define SSH2_DISCONNECT_HOST_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED      4
#define SSH2_DISCONNECT_RESERVED                        4
#define SSH2_DISCONNECT_MAC_ERROR                       5
#define SSH2_DISCONNECT_COMPRESSION_ERROR               6
#define SSH2_DISCONNECT_SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE           7
#define SSH2_DISCONNECT_PROTOCOL_VERSION_NOT_SUPPORTED  8
#define SSH2_DISCONNECT_HOST_KEY_NOT_VERIFIABLE         9
#define SSH2_DISCONNECT_CONNECTION_LOST                 10
#define SSH2_DISCONNECT_BY_APPLICATION                  11
#define SSH2_DISCONNECT_TOO_MANY_CONNECTIONS            12
#define SSH2_DISCONNECT_AUTH_CANCELLED_BY_USER          13
#define SSH2_DISCONNECT_NO_MORE_AUTH_METHODS_AVAILABLE  14
#define SSH2_DISCONNECT_ILLEGAL_USER_NAME               15
```

Answer (score 0):

Look above that line. Do you see something like " Did not receive identification string from " or something similar? They are likely attacking attempts.